# Filter large XML file with xslt and child contains text

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I have a large XML file (20 MB) and I want to make it smaller by filtering only  the relevant elements. For filtering I need to get the nodes where the element "Allterms" contains the word "Energy".

The XML source is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<nodes>
  <node>
    <Titel>The title here</Titel>
    <Allterms>Term1; Term2</Allterms>
    <Shorttext>&amp;lt;div&amp;gt;HTML text &amp;lt;/div&amp;gt;</Shorttext>
    <Nid>3433333</Nid>
    <Year>2015</Year>
  </node>
  <node>
    <Titel>The title here</Titel>
    <Allterms>Term1; Term2; Energy</Allterms>
    <Shorttext>&amp;lt;div&amp;gt;HTML text &amp;lt;/div&amp;gt;</Shorttext>
    <Nid>2211338</Nid>
    <Year>2014</Year>
  </node>
</nodes>
```

I want to create the same XML with XSLT but the new XML should only have `<node>` where `<Allterms>`  contains the word "Energy".

I found examples and tried them, but they do not seem to work:
 - test="contains(Allterms, 'Energy')
 - and also match="nodes/node[contains(Allterms, 'Energy')]

A> How should my XSLT look to get the desired result?
B> Do I use Internet Explorer for the XSLT and the 20 MB XML to get the smaller filtered XML? Or is there a better tool?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use an XSLT stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node[not(contains(Allterms, 'Energy'))]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To use XSLT to transform XML to XML I would suggest to use an XML IDE or editor like oXygen, Stylus Studio, Altova XMLSpy or an XSLT plugin to your favorite programming editor or IDE or any XSLT processor you can run from the command line.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Also the tip for the tools was useful. I downloaded oXygen (30 days trial) and this helped testing / debugging the XSL. Also it did run the XSLT + big XML pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

Martin's solution is correct and general, but this one is so simple I would probably write it as

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <nodes>
   <xsl:copy-of select="/*/node[contains(Allterms, 'Energy')]"/> 
  </nodes>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In fact when the problem is as simple as this I often prefer XQuery, where it's a one-liner:

```
<nodes>{/*/node[contains(Allterms, 'Energy')]}</nodes>
```

Answer (score -1):

A)
Always be specific and state in the condition that you want to test a text node with contains. (Otherwise, it won't work usualy). Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="node">
        <xsl:if test="Allterms[descendant::text()[contains(., 'Energy')]]">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What `<xsl:if test="Allterms[descendant::text()[contains(., 'Energy')]]">` does is: Test if there is at least one text node inside `Allterms` wich contains the string 'Engergy'. Edit: The benefit is that will work even if you decide later to wrap 'Energy' in a nother element (which is something that I my projects happened quite a lot).

As for B) you might want to have a look into Oxygen XML Editor. It is a very powerful tool and comes with several XSLT processors.

Comment: Using `/text()` is usually wrong; certainly it's wrong when there is no mixed content. This code will fail if there are XML comments in particular places in the source.

Comment: @Michael Kay Sorry, sir, but I can't imagine which "particular places" you mean. I tried by adding `<!-- foo -->` in virtually every bit of the given sample XML - and my code still works.

Comment: @Michael Kay Concering mixed content, you're right, of course. Modified my post.

Comment: Well, putting it in the middle of the word "Energy" would certainly cause the word not to be found.